# How can I pick image Directly from recycler view instead of gallery or camera to set on wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-crop

I am developing a wallpaper app with pixabay and retrofit.
I have been trying to select image from the recycler view but I am unable to do so.[Referring to the image attached below, when i press customize button i want to crop the image selected and not from galley or camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xePFH.png)
I have searched an tried almost everything but only thing that happens is image picker opens and asks to pick image from galley or camera.
Can some one please give a hint or a sample code
Here is what I am trying to do

1. Pick image from my recycler view , I have a button of crop , I will click that and direct cropper opens and crops the image selected and not from gallery or camera.

Comment: Hi @Hassan, some more info needed on what you're trying to do and maybe add some code with what you did so far...

Comment: hey , please check the attached image.